# How to play a song when a virus is detected with clamav?

Tags: music, antivirus, clamav

How to play a song when a virus is detected with clamav from command line ?
A song and not a bell .

For information I do this to scan with a bell :  clamscan -r --bell -i /media

Thanks,

Comment: Write a script `clamscan -i ... ; [ $? -eq 1 ] && aplay /path/to/song` Cant be more specific with what little you posted .

Comment: Post your script / command as an answer you did the work, I just nudged you .

Answer (score 0):

It appears clamscan(1) sends its output to stdout so pipe it to tee which will send the output to stdout and to a command that filters for "Virus detected" and whan that is found, it invokes your program to play music. From the clam AntiVirus user's manual, it appears the output will be what this line produces:

> printf("Virus detected: %s\n", virname);

Something like this should work:

```
clamscan |tee (grep "Virus detected" | yourprogram_or_script musicfile )
```

See https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vrtadmin/clamav-faq/master/manual/clamdoc.pdf and clamscan(1) and tee(1) for more info.

Comment: I have tried that but sorry this do not work and that is more easy  : `; [ $?-eq 1] && `

For example : `/usr/bin/clamscan -r -l /var/log/clamscan_sched_$d.log  /home/pi/Desktop; [ $? -eq 1 ] &&  espeak  -v en+f2 -s 150 'Warning, a virus has been detected' `

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, FI0RlAN-X answered with :

```
/usr/bin/clamscan -r -l /var/log/clamscan_sched_$d.log /home/pi/Desktop; [ $? -eq 1 ] && espeak -v en+f2 -s 150 'Warning, a virus has been detected'
```

To break that up a bit, the clamscan options, from [man clamscan](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/clamscan.1.html%20%22man%20clamscan)

> -r, --recursive
>
> ```
>           Scan  directories  recursively.  All  the  subdirectories in the
>           given directory will be scanned.
> ```
>
> -l FILE, --log=FILE
>
> ```
>           Save scan report to FILE.
> ```
>
> RETURN CODES
>
> ```
>   0 : No virus found.
>
>   1 : Virus(es) found.
>
>   2 : Some error(s) occured.
> ```

So the second comand, `$?` is the return code from clamscan , so test if the retrun code is 1 (virus found) `[ $? -eq 1 ]` and play a sound using a sound with espeak `espeak -v en+f2 -s 150 'Warning, a virus has been detected'`

```
[ $? -eq 1 ] && espeak -v en+f2 -s 150 'Warning, a virus has been detected'
```